# Update a color value during runtime in Android

Tags: java, android, json, android-theme

I'm currently working on an Android application with a default theme. The layouts use colors defined in the colors.xml file:

```
<resources>

    <color name="colorPrimary">#FF0DB94E</color>
    <color name="textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="accentColor">#FF1744</color>
    <color name="windowBackgroundPrimary">#F2F2F2</color>
    ...
</resources>
```

I want to update those values dynamically: the app fetches a JSON file from an URL, the data is stored in an array. This part is already coded. The JSON file would be as simple as that:

```
{
  "colorPrimary":"#00B0EB",
  "textColorPrimary":"#FFFFFFFF",
  "accentColor":"#FFFFFFFF",
  "windowBackgroundPrimary":"#FFFFFFFF",
  ...
}
```

My problem is that I have no idea how to modify those color values. The R.java file they are stored in can't be accessed after being compiled, and modifying all the color references in my layouts with loops doesn't seem the best way to do it.

Anyone has any clue of a good way to do this?

For now I have several options in mind, but I don't really know how to implement them:

- Provide an external APK with another version of the color.xml file
- Create a intermediate class which contains all the references of the colors used by the layouts

Thanks for your help

Comment: Since the resource files in your app are immutable, another idea would be to save your colors in a `SharedPreference`. Then reload these at startup.

Comment: You can't change the resources once the app has been compiled, so option 2 (creating a wrapper between your implementation and the resources/json) would be the best approach, imho

Answer (score 0):

Use this method in Activity class

```
getResources().getColor(int id)
```

id:ResourceId

Answer (score 0):

There are some methods related to themes in Activity like activity.setTheme(R.style.MyTheme) etc. But all of them are operating with R.style identifiers.

So in short you are right. There are only 2 options:

1. APK if you prefer external theming
2. Intermediate class which will be used for wrapping colors data for internal dynamic theming